# Maven Java GAE compilation error

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I'm getting a build failure with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project r esponderhub: Compilation failure
>   [ERROR]
>   /X:/Workspaces/ResponderHubWorkspace/responderhub/src/main/java/uk/org/responderhub/MemberServlet.java:[23,110]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   method now() [ERROR] location:
>   class com.googlecode.objectify.Ref

with the following simple source code:

```
package uk.org.responderhub;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

import uk.org.responderhub.data.Member;

public class MemberServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    Member member = new Member();
    member.userid="1234";

    ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(member);

    Member member2 = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Member.class).filter("userid", member.userid).first().now();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following the Google App Engine tutorial for Java there was a typo in the pom.xml changes it lists when it talks about adding objectify to the dependencies. The version of objectify is supposed to be listed as 4.0.1, not 4.0b1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- Update to [maven to 3.2.5](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
- Make sure you have [java jdk version 1.7.x](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) running and the same version is stated in your pom.xml: `<configuration><source>1.7</sourc><target>1.7</target></configuration>`
- Update app engine in your pom.xml to the latest 1.9.22: `<appengine.target.version>1.9.22</appengine.target.version>`
- Delete the .m2 in your directory:

  - Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2
  - Windows – C:\Documents and Settings\your-username\ .m2
- Run ‘mvn clean install’

Post your pom.xml if the error persists.